# Passing a selected checkbox value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a table, and the last column in the table has a checkbox, when the user clicks on a a check box, i want to pass a row value to a different function, but when i do this, the code doesn't seem to be firing, am i missing something ?

```
 function GetContractors(companyName) {

    var workforce = companyName;

    $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("getContractors","Permit")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "workforce": workforce },
        success: function (result) {

            $("#mainData").empty();

            $.each(JSON.parse(result),
                function (i, item) {

                    var row = i + 1;

                    $("#mainData").append(

                        "<tr>" +

                        "<td id='process_"  + row + "'" + ">" + item.ContractorName + "</td>" +

                        "<td bgcolor= " + "'" + cellColour1 + "'" + " id='process_" + row + "'" + ">" + parseJsonDate(item.InductionExpiry) + "</td>" +

                        "<td bgcolor= " + "'" + cellColour + "'" + " id='process_" + row + "'" + ">" + parseJsonDate(item.InsuranceExpiry) + "</td>" +

                        "<td id='Action" + row + "'" + ">" +

                        "<checkbox id='checkbox' class='btn btn-xs btn-success " +
                        "'" + "onclick='SelectedUser(" + item.ContractorName + ")" +
                        "'" + ">" + "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash" +
                        "'" + "></i>" + "</checkbox>" + "&nbsp" +

                       "</tr>");

                });
        },
        error: function (result) {

            alert(result);
        }
    });
};

  function SelectedUser(name) 
  {
    alert(name);
    }
```

Comment: _`want to pass a row value to a different function`_ You are just passing `{ "workforce": workforce },` Am I missing something?

Comment: If value of `item.ContractorName` is say `john`, javascript will see the onclick handler code as `SelectedUser(john)`, so javascript wil ltry to look for a variable named john which doesnt exists and error will be thrown. TLDR: Hardcoded string argument is missing quotes.

Comment: i want to pass "contractorName"  to the function selectUser when the checkbox is clicked

Comment: try onchange instead of onclick. Plus see in your DOM what exactly is rendered.

Comment: Declare your function "window.SelectedUser = function(name){ ... };"

Comment: No such thing as a `<checkbox>` element in html unless it is a custom element

Comment: so have you got a solution? @MatJ

Comment: @user1483145, As I said, add quotes inside the parenthesis, `onclick='SelectedUser('" + item.ContractorName + "')`

Comment: Time to learn to look for errors in browser dev tools console. Should see big clue there

Comment: @MatJ i added these in, still not hitting the function selecteduser?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
"onclick='SelectedUser(\"" + item.ContractorName + "\")" +
```

You were passing:

```
onclick='SelectedUser(Bob)'
```

which would expect an object, but should be

```
onclick='SelectedUser("Bob")'
```

`\"` escapes the double-quote

Comment: Legend! All i was missing was the single quotes, as i compared this in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

If the value is a string pass it between apostrophes, like so:

`SelectedUser(" ' + item.ContractorName + ' ")`.